# XAML WinRT - Factory Pattern for Custom Styles

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'd like to implement a sort of Factory Pattern for XAML. I created an app for WinRT where I defined two xaml style files. Basically, what I'd like to achieve (if possible) is to load one of the the two xaml file when the application starts.
in the solution explorer I have this:

[image]

**CustomStyles foder** contains the style files. So, based on an enumerator in my **App.xaml.cs** file

```
public enum Style
{
    Style_1,
    Style_2
}
```

if I choose **Style_1** I'd like to load the xaml file **Style_1.xaml** else **Style_2.xaml** at run-time.
Both the style files, have the same definition of Button style, TextBlock style, etc with different property values. 
Here an example:

**Style_1.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="Attribute_Label" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#78CAB3" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
</Style>
```

**Style_2.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="Attribute_Label" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#606060" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
</Style>
```

There is a way to achieve what I want to do ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for [Theming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150570/how-to-implement-theming-in-wpf). I'm not sure what level of support WinRT XAML has for that, though.

Comment: Do you still need a bounty? :)

Comment: If you wish to add more reputation, feel free :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We end up to do something like this:

1. defining a **ResourcesDictionary** in App.xaml with all the CustomStyles
2. we make a server request that decides which custom style has to be loaded
3. using this piece of code `Application.Current.Resources[CustomStyleVariable];` we load the whole style in a Style object.

We haven't found any better solution yet but, it seems to work.