# How to set skin name before initializing a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Main window with radio-buttons and a button that open the next window. The next window has big user controls which are made up of many identical smaller user controls. Now when a radio-button is selected it sends its name to the small user controls where it is used as the name of the library for each skin. (The skins are only changing the apperances of small user controls.)

Now the problem I have is that the name of the library reaches the small user control only after its been initialized, which is too late as by then the value of the string name is already considered null and no skin is loaded.

This is the code from the small user control:

```
  public string name ="";
    public bool SetSkin(string _Banananas)
    {
        name = _Banananas;

        return true;
    }
    public SW1()
    {       
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnSkinChanged;
        DataContext = this;
        IsBlinking = false;

    }


    private void OnSkinChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        mg.Resources.Clear();
          mg.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

        ResourceDictionary skin = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/TestingApp;component/Resources/Skins/" + name + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
        mg.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(skin);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

_Banananas is the string I get from the radio-button.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what the `mg` object is that you are using in your `OnSkinChanged` method, but I assume, that you use the `App` object here.

**The problem you are facing is that in WPF the loaded event is raised right after the user interface object is initialized and before you can call any methods on the newly created window or user control.**

One "dirty" way to solve this problem is to create another constructor that receives the skin value as a parameter, like so:

```cs
public SW1(string skin)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetSkin(skin);
    Loaded += OnSkinChanged;
    DataContext = this;
    IsBlinking = false;
}
```

Of course, you would have to call this constructor (not the default one) on the code section that creates this user control.

However, there are patterns how to use dynamic themes in WPF and your code doesn't seem to follow them. Just google it or have a look at other questions on Stack Overflow, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151024/1560623

Comment: Thanks for the respose, the mg object is the grid in SW1, and SW1 is the actual small user control so this won't work (I tried), I tried to google it in many different ways but I'm not finding anything usefull so far, I checked your link and am now googling it further, but the thing is I'm not using mvvm, and it's a bit too far now to transform into it, I think. I found some pages on dynamic skinning but none that would have a similary nested set controls.

Comment: Do you use `DynamicResource` in the XAML files of your User Controls? If yes, then you could exchange the styles dynamically at runtime - I would even advise that you do this at the application level. You do not have to follow the MVVM pattern to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I do use dynamic resource. And I would change skins earlier at a higher level but he thing is that when the open button is pressed the window inits and the BW1 (the big user control) gets multiplied according to the data, populated with SW1s accordingly and this all happens one initialization after another instantly. So I think I need a way to refresh the SW1s or something right after the name string  changes its value...

Comment: I'm wondering why it does not work in your case then... Maybe you should post more of your code or provide an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because according to your descriptions, it should work.

Comment: I would post more code but  it's 4 documents with round 180 lines each  (+ XAML for all four of 'em) and almost all of it is relevant since it's mostly specific nesting and mapping... Ill try to make an abridged version later today or tomorrow and post it...