# What is the proper way to create UI settings in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, settings

I'm working now on a base Style in XAML which includes a Template for my standard `HandledWindow` type.
The style includes several local resources like colours, fonts and other variables to reuse later in my style.

I was thinking of UI settings for the user, so he can change things like colours and sizes as he wishes.
But then I've discovered that changing the local resource won't change the style itself but only for the current `HandledWindow` instance, So it's not suitable way for UI settings since there might be more then running window in the application.

Then I realised I have to bind variables relatively to the template of my `HandledWindow` class, which will include all changeable settings as public & static properties. But then I encountered an issue with static property binding since I cannot raise the `PropertyChanged` event which works only for an instance. And the window won't update it's style by itself.

In addition I am trying to make the style react and update immediately on the fly without restarts.

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML. BTW WPF has [Built-in support for themes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11139598/643085), which is utterly absent in dinosaur winforms, that's why you were forced to all sorts of horrible hacks in winforms, whereas in WPF everything is beautiful and happy.

Comment: The theme trick is done by replacing the resources of the current instance of an `HandledWindow`, I was thinking of that too, But I need something that will change the theme for other windows at the same moment like data binding, without even loading any XAML pages just by C# code only, Setting a new value for the property, and the visual UI should be updated at the same moment. I will post my code in several minutes.

Note that these static public properties should be editable by UI too, It means there should be another data binding to set it from the UI.

Comment: No. If you want application-wide themes load your resource dictionaries in `System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources`.

Comment: I will try that, Currently I am loading the base style as an application resource (thorough `ResourceDictionary`) in the entry `ApplicationDefinition` XAML page. So I think changing the whole theme won't be tough.

But how can I let the user change a specific UI setting, Not the whole theme, I want to let the user change specific UI variables by a settings interface like MVVM mechanics with data binding.

BTW I have posted the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is "resource-centric". You define all your UI styles, brushes and templates in your resources and at runtime it is very easy to enable application-wide theme change that would encompass all the properties you mention. Here is how I do it in my MainViewModel after it receives a message from my Settings Window via its SettingsViewModel:

```
private void ApplyTheme()
{          
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    var rd = new ResourceDictionary { { "Locator", locator } };
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);

    switch (theme)
    {
        case "Blue":
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Blue;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Blue;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Blue;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Blue;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Blue;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            break;
        case "Summer":
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Summer;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Summer;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Summer;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Summer;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Summer;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            break;
        }
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Resources/Brushes.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Resources/ControlTemplates.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Resources/DataTemplates.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Resources/Styles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
    }
```

Obviously I am using Telerik controls so I load their dictionaries but at the bottom of the method you'll notice I load my own resources like Brushes, Styles etc. as well.

In conclusion, application-wide theme changes could not be easier with WPF.